# Revert --all in TortoiseHg Workbench

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, revert

Simple question: is there a way to revert --all from TortoiseHg workbench?  I see how to revert an individual file.  Ideally, I could click on a revision, and from the right mouse menu find a "revert all" item.

I'm using TortoiseHg 2.8 on a Ubuntu box.

EDIT I should have provided more details on my question to provide some context.  Let me describe the particular use case:

I want to put my working directory back to the state of a past commit so I can generate output from the executable that I know was "good".  Once I've generated that output, I want to go back to the tip and continue my development, keeping this history linear.  From the command line, I did "hg revert --all --rev 22", generated the output, then "hg revert --all", which did what I wanted.  "hg update" will create a history with a branch (if I'm understanding correctly).  FWIW there *is* an "update" button in TortoiseHg (in the box where the list of files is shown) as well as a right-mouse menu item on a given revision.

Answer (score 10):

To set the working directory to match the state of a given changeset (which could be `tip`), you can use Update:

1. Right click on the changeset you want to 'revert' to.
2. Select "Update"
3. Check the "Discard local changes" checkbox
4. Click Update

It would be `hg update -r changeset -C` in the console.

Now you can create the output from the 'state' of the working directory at that point in history (i.e. from the executable at that changeset). If you don't make any commits here there will be no changeset created and therefore nothing is added to the repo history.

Once you have the output to your satisfaction, you can update again to the `tip` of development via the same process and continue your work:

1. Right click on the `tip` of development.
2. Select "Update"
3. Check the "Discard local changes" checkbox
4. Click update

The benefit of using `update` over `revert` is that Tortoise will explicitly display the parent of the working directory as the changeset it history. Under `revert` it could be very easy to revert the files and lose track of which changeset you had reverted to and which part of history you occupied.

(This is assuming that you want to move to that point in the history. If you need to create a changeset that undoes a prior changeset, look into [backout](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Backout), though I'm not sure if that is available in Tortoise.)

---

Comment: Thanks for the info.  See the edit of my OP.  "Update" would mostly work for what I wanted but it is a little more heavy-handed than "revert", but maybe my use case is a little unusual.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all modified files in the list with Ctrl+A and then select "Revert" from context menu.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  The one difficulty with this approach (unless I'm missing something) is that there is no convenient way to find what are all the files that have changed between the current working directory and the desired revision.  (There is a "diff to local" which will invoke the separate visual diff tool, but there isn't a good way to launch "revert" from there.)